# Go type method not equal to instance method

Tags: go

```
type T struct {
    Tp int
}

func (t T) Set(a int) {

    t.Tp = a
}
func main() {
    t := T{}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(t.Set))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(T.Set))
}

result :
func(int)
func(main.T, int)
```

why T.set is not equal to t.set?
what is principle or translation  bebind this?

http://play.golang.org/p/xYnWZ3PlyF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t.Set is a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values). T.Set is a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions).

The method value `t.Set` yields a function equivalent to:

```
func(a int) ( t.Set(a) }
```

The method expression `T.Set` yields a function that is equivalent to the method with the receiver as the first argument.

```
func(t T, a int) { t.Set(a) }
```

This [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/UE6GyVdCeI) illustrates the difference between the method value and method expression.

Separate from this discussion about method expressions and method values, 
the function Set should take a pointer receiver. Otherwise, the change to t is discarded.

```
func (t *T) Set(a int) {
   t.Tp = a
}
```

Here's the [example](http://play.golang.org/p/c74S5b9vIz) with the pointer receiver.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I think T.Set is expression and t.Set is value. Typo I think?

Comment: Really helpful ! Solve the  problem confused me all day long Thanks@3fo3